# Sorting using AI / neural net

Tags: machine-learning, sorting, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

I have a search operation taking place on a server that essentially queries images using `OpenCV` against other images from a database. Since each image query operation is quite expensive computationally, I want to find a good way to sort the images in the database to compare them in a good order. I want the program to be more likely to find a good match early and less likely to have to try all the images in the database to get a match. I suspect there would be strong correlations between data about the user carrying out the search (such as his age, gender, location, etc...) and the likelihood of him searching for a particular image, taking into account the history of users who successfully searched for this image and their data.

I was thinking this could be achieved with a neural network, however, I haven't found anything online about doing such type of sorting with one. Maybe I could use some type of machine learning to create a score for each item in the database and then use conventional sorting. Could you kindly recommend what might be a good approach to this?

Comment: Sorting is generally not an operation you would do with machine learning, as we have fairly efficient algorithms to do sorting, once the order between any pair is known. I suspect that you want to either use machine learning to determine an order, or to heuristically find a small subset of 'interesting' samples.

Comment: Or perhaps what you'd ideally want is some kind of "index" of your images in the database. But that will likely be very high-dimensional to be meaningful for your purposes, and might be too much to do efficiently. In any case, I do not think 'sorting' accurately describes your problem, so please clarify how what I described would fit with what you'd want.

Comment: @Discretelizard thanks for your reply! Yes I think an index would be great and then I could just use any good sorting algo to order the search. Perhaps a neural net that calculates the indexes for a given input of data?

Comment: Hmm. I'm still not exactly sure what it is you want. Do you want to preprocess (a function of) your data on the server such that it will help you with _any_ query you will make afterwards? Or do you want a less expensive function that finds likely matches based on the _given_ query image?

Comment: the latter: a less expensive function that finds likely matches based on the given query image

Comment: What are the semantics of a query?  There are many kinds of queries that are possible.  Is your query to search for an identical image?  A similar image?  Something else?  What algorithm do you currently use for handling queries?  What would count as a "good order" -- is your concern efficiency, or is your concern about the quality of the result?  Can you [edit] your question to clarify all of these points, make it read well for someone who encounters the question for the first time, and spare people from having to read the comments to understand your question?